# While click on Reset (UIButton) Application is Closed

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios

In my Monotouch application having the UIImageview to display the dicom images also one Reset Button. 
I use various UIGestureRecognizer on it while applying the Pinch or Rotate or any 1 of these UIGestureRecognizer it perform the operation very well. But while click on the Reset Button image get reset and application at the same instance get is closed. 
 I don't want to close the application while click on Reset Button

my code is

```
 override void ViewDidLoad() 
{ 
this.BtnReset.TouchDown += ResetHandler; 
} 
void ResetHandler (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
ImgView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity (); 
}
```

Comment: Is it normal to write function and variable names with a big first letter in mono touch?

Comment: As C# is using PascalCase, it's used in MonoTouch too.

Comment: Is ImgView null in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this:

- Does this occur on simulator, on phone or both?
- Does the Application Output tell you anything about what's going wrong - e.g. a crash trace?
- Can you see the debug output - e.g. on the console in xcode.
- Can you put a breakpoint in the ResetHandler method - can you debug it?

It's hard to see any issue with the code as is - perhaps this might be as simple as the variable being null or perhaps you are hitting some jit/aot compiler or linker error.